# Facebook posting error in ios

Tags: iphone, ios, facebook, cocos2d-iphone

Here i am trying to add a post to facebook using following code.

```
FBAppCall *appCall = [FBDialogs presentShareDialogWithLink:urlToShare
                                                          name:@"Title"
                                                       caption:nil
                                                   description:@"description"
                                                       picture:nil
                                                   clientState:nil
                                                       handler:^(FBAppCall *call, NSDictionary *results, NSError *error) {
                                                           if (error) {
                                                               NSLog(@"Error: %@", error.description);
                                                           } else {
                                                               NSLog(@"Success!");
                                                           }
                                                       }];
```

But this isn't working. It give following error.

`Error Domain=com.facebook.Facebook.platform Code=102 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (com.facebook.Facebook.platform error 102.)" UserInfo=0x1cde3340 {error_code=102, action_id=E780C3AA-1387-4B9C-9A3A-9A16FB54BC59, error_message=An error occurred during publishing., app_id=558567750859724}`

Here i am working on `cocos2d`, is this can be the reason.

Comment: Looks like an OAuth error. Check here: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/errors/

Comment: can u let me knw ponce u finish ths?

Comment: I have integrated the new SDK and have this problem too. I'm not using cocos2D therefore I don't think it's related to that.

Comment: developing for which ios version?

Comment: What worked for you? I am facing the same issues and adapted answer below is not working for me.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Go to your app's settings under the Facebook developer portal.

Go to open graph > types

Choose the action type using and turn on "User Generated Images" for that action type. Save these settings and try again. It will work.

Comment: Could you please point out where is the "User Generated Images"? I assume that its 1) add a new action type 2) select "publish" Thanks

Comment: It's under Apps > Your app > Types > Action Type

Comment: I've done everything above with the same exact code and I'm still getting this error. Please help. I've also disabled sandbox mode with no luck.

Comment: What is action type you mentioned here to add? I see plan, want and review as options. can't locate "using" if using is what you meant to enable "User Generated Images".

Answer (score 3):

I encountered this error as well, make sure you disable the sandbox mode in Facebook admin panel before distributing to any other user :P

Answer (score 1):

I recently encountered this error when the link I tried to post did not load correctly (was loading a 404 page). Not sure why, but maybe Facebook requires the link work.. Either way they need to make their error messaging more specific.