# Facebook SDK Share Dialog Error for iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, facebook, sdk, share

No matter what I do, I get this error when I share:

> 2014-02-03 00:13:36.392 Kurt Osiander[4443:60b] Error publishing story: Error Domain=com.facebook.Facebook.platform Code=102 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (com.facebook.Facebook.platform error 102.)" UserInfo=0x15d475b0 {error_message=An error occurred during publishing., app_id=xxxxxxxxxx, error_code=102}

I've disabled sandbox mode and messed around with open graph options ([Facebook posting error in ios](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17667864/facebook-posting-error-in-ios)) with no luck. My code is attached below:

```
// Check if the Facebook app is installed and we can present the share dialog

    FBShareDialogParams *params = [[FBShareDialogParams alloc] init];
    params.link = [NSURL URLWithString:@"https://http://www.kurtosiander.com/"];
    params.name = @"Kurt Osiander's Move of the Week";
    params.caption = @"Kurt Osiander's Move of the Week";
    params.picture = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://a5.mzstatic.com/us/r30/Purple/v4/4b/7e/73/4b7e737c-bdc1-2aa5-3288-4e76c658235b/mzl.yafqehvw.175x175-75.jpg"];
    params.description = @"Kurt's iPhone app is finally available! Check it out now to learn all his moves, organized by position and submission.";

    // If the Facebook app is installed and we can present the share dialog
    if ([FBDialogs canPresentShareDialogWithParams:params]) {
        // Present share dialog
        NSLog(@"Present Dialog");
        [FBDialogs presentShareDialogWithLink:params.link
                                         name:params.name
                                      caption:params.caption
                                  description:params.description
                                      picture:params.picture
                                  clientState:nil
                                      handler:^(FBAppCall *call, NSDictionary *results, NSError *error) {
                                          NSLog(@"handling");
                                          if(error) {
                                              // An error occurred, we need to handle the error
                                              // See: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/ios/errors
                                              NSLog(@"%@", [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Error publishing story: %@", error.description]);
                                          } else {
                                              // Success
                                              NSLog(@"result %@", results);
                                          }
                                      }];
```

In my app delegate:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application
            openURL:(NSURL *)url
  sourceApplication:(NSString *)sourceApplication
         annotation:(id)annotation {

    BOOL urlWasHandled = [FBAppCall handleOpenURL:url
                                sourceApplication:sourceApplication
                                  fallbackHandler:^(FBAppCall *call) {
                                      NSLog(@"Unhandled deep link: %@", url);
                                      // Here goes the code to handle the links
                                      // Use the links to show a relevant view of your app to the user
                                  }];

    return urlWasHandled;
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Facebook SDK - iOS - Fail to share URL (Error 102)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18541510/facebook-sdk-ios-fail-to-share-url-error-102)

Comment: My FacebookDisplayName is the same for my plist entry and my Facebook app settings. Unfortunately, this is not the issue.

Comment: still you have this problem?

Comment: yes i still have the issue... everything i saw that people said fixed the issue didn't work for me.

Comment: Here is my plist: https://www.evernote.com/shard/s237/sh/5d5df7d0-123f-4062-b02f-1b4409b1733e/ed16158acc25f18f4c9bf4782c120b16
Here are my facebook app settings:
https://www.evernote.com/shard/s237/sh/b77f1d67-b131-45ec-bbd6-b95c354a8713/4e204671a05cd105930718aa239d806c

Comment: as i can see , you have not given it a bundle identifier for app. it must be same as it is in your facebook developer  ios page.

Comment: The bundle identifier looks like that in plist but is generated properly in my target settings. Should I hard code it in the plists?
https://www.evernote.com/shard/s237/sh/caf79f45-4589-44f9-baff-2459e5749b53/b325a5a523cb31aa7f97a6cea2c9da55

Comment: I tried changing the bundle identifier in the plist and it didn't solve the issue :( I also added my app delegate code to my description above just in case there's an issue there

Answer (score 0):

I have a similar problem and I think they are bosed based on the facebook display name. In yours there is a special character and in mine there is a german umlaut.

So I would suggest to remove the special character (') on the facebook app and in the plist.
I hope this helps even if this is not a satisfyinf soultion for the problem ([FacebookDisplayName on iOS with german umlauts [SOLVED]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22050613/facebookdisplayname-on-ios-with-german-umlauts)).

UPDATE: I found a soultion! The problem is a result of the utf8 string representation and the linked string comparision difference.
Here is my workaround:

```
[FBSettings setDefaultDisplayName:[[FBSettings defaultDisplayName] precomposedStringWithCanonicalMapping]];
```