# FacebookDisplayName on iOS with german umlauts

Tags: ios, facebook

I have a facebook iOS integration and with my test facebook app everything worked fine. Now after I changed the facebook app id and display name to the live facebook app I get the error 102

> "Failed to authenticate the application because of app name mismatch.  Please check the application name configured by the dialog"

The facebook app display name has a german umlaut: ö
I think this is the problem.
Just found this question: [Facebook IOS App DisplayName and German Umlauts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20497918/facebook-ios-app-displayname-and-german-umlauts)

Answer (score 1):

Found the solution by my self.
The problem results of the different utf8 character representation and the resulting difference in a string comparison.
My solution:

```
[FBSettings setDefaultDisplayName:[[FBSettings defaultDisplayName] precomposedStringWithCanonicalMapping]];
```